# Should we prefer mean of absolute or square Shapley values?

Tags: python, shapley-value

Usually (for linear models at least) Shapley values are defined as deviations to some mean. By default, it seems the bar plot of the popular python package [shap](https://github.com/slundberg/shap) diplays the mean of absolute Shapley values and there is no `root_square_mean` property on the `shap.Explanation` class to get a plot of standard deviations.

Is there a reason why mean absolute difference is preferred to standard deviation in such case ?

Comment: What would be the meaning of the squared values?

Comment: @Tim, the mean of a Shapley value as computed [here](https://shap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_notebooks/overviews/An%20introduction%20to%20explainable%20AI%20with%20Shapley%20values.html) is zero across the dataset. Hence the mean of its square would correspond to its variance isn't it ?

Comment: Variance of what?

Comment: @Tim, it would be an estimate of the variance of the distribution followed by the shap value ?

Comment: How this would be useful?

Comment: @Tim, it would quantify the importance of the feature associated to this shapley value for the model. A bit like the mean absolute difference does. I was wondering why the mean absolute difference was used in place of the standard deviation when this is usually the more popular option in statistics.

Comment: @Tim One advantage of using the square is that it would quantify how correlated the Shapley values are since the variance of a sum of independents variables is the sum of their variance. If the sum of the variance of the Shapley values is equal to the variance of the model then the features of our model must be independent. There may be some other arguments too.